# ViewsPlugin.class is missing in this org.eclipse.ui.views_3.9.0.v20170226-1833.jar Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

ViewsPlugin.class is missing in this org.eclipse.ui.views_3.9.0.v20170226-1833.jar plugin.

Anyone know, Please give the suggest me. Any alternate option.

Comment: What problem is its absence causing?

Comment: @nitind In this class has so many methods like as: ViewsPlugin.getViewImageDescriptor("abc.gif"), becoz this method, already used my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That class was internal, so it shouldn't have been used in other plugins in the first place.

It was removed in [Bug 478242](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478242). See the Gerrit change there for details.

If you need the PLUGIN_ID (for whatever reason), you can use

```
FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ContentOutline.class).getBundleId();
// or use any other class from that bundle instead of `ContentOutline`
```

If you need the `getAdapter` utility method which was there earlier, use

```
Adapters.getAdapter(object, adapter, true);
```

as noted in [Bug 478333](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478333).

If you need the replacement for `getViewImageDescriptor`, then use

```
private ImageDescriptor createImageDescriptor(String relativeIconPath) 
{
    String ICONS_PATH = "$nl$/icons/full/";//$NON-NLS-1$
    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ContentOutline.class);
    ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(
        String.valueOf(bundle.getBundleId()), 
        ICONS_PATH + relativeIconPath);
    return imageDescriptor;
}
```

(taken from [this changeset](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/commit/?id=37b0d491723e25e33737f2a0c2815b08dc66e38c))

Comment: I want to use for  this ViewsPlugin.getViewImageDescriptor("abc.gif") method. Do you have any alternate solutions.